# Надо синонимизировать [текстура] и [texture]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Есть две похожие метки: [текстура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0) и [texture](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/texture). Хорошо бы их синонимизировать. Не знаю уж в пользу кого, но подозреваю, что лучше в пользу [текстура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0), потому что у неё есть описание. Хотя у метки [texture](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/texture) в два раза больше вопросов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

готово!

```
updating post history, 49 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 44 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 42 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'texture': [texture] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 70
tag remapping of [текстура] and [texture] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym texture -> текстура was approved!
```